# Where is windows terminal setting location (json file) in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, terminal

I saw a youtube video in which by editing the json file of cmd they could make the interafce of windows cmd better but it was in windows 11 not 10.

I wanted to access the both json and the location setting file of command line which can be edited in windows 11. But I got a problem on finding it in windows 10. Does anyone have any idea about it?

I searched and know that there is a file at this location :

> C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows
> Terminal\settings.json

but I can't find it in my windows 10 desktop.

Answer (score 2):

See Microsoft's Windows Terminal documentation at
[Settings JSON file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install#settings-json-file) :

> The path for your Windows Terminal settings.json file may be found in
> one of the following directories:
>
> - Terminal (stable / general release): `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json`
> - Terminal (preview release): `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json`
> - Terminal (unpackaged: Scoop, Chocolately, etc): `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\settings.json`

You have found the location for the third one, which is for
"unpackaged: Scoop, Chocolately, etc".

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I searched all the locations you mentioned but I couldn't find it in any one of them.
My windows is 10 and its version is 22H2.

Comment: Same Windows version, and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json` is there for me. How exactly are you checking for it?